# linux system daemon in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, daemon

I need to write some linux specific system daemon(it will run with root privileges).

I have stereotype, that Qt is all about GUI applications, so daemon that depends on Qt looks strange to me.

On the other side, Qt has nice C++ bindings for DBUS/threads/settings/... - everything i need for my daemon.

Now I am interested, is it okay to write non GUI system tools/daemons with Qt? Are there examples of such tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it okay to write non GUI system tools/daemons with Qt?

Yes, this is perfectly fine.

There is the [QCoreApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html) class for non UI applications.

Specific to daemons, you might want to check out [Daemonizing a Qt-application](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26923-Daemonizing-a-Qt-application).

Comment: This link is broken. Currently some info is here http://forum.qt.io/topic/39150/qtservice-or-how-to-run-qcoreapplication-as-a-service/2

Answer (score 2):

Since Qt4, Qt library has been splitted in a number of modules.

You could use Qt Core without having even installed Qt Gui or any other graphical thing.

I can think of a fiew command line only examples that use Qt (like `qdbus`)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, QT is not all about GUI. It is a complete framework for cross platform development.

You can sure make a deamon using QT. However, what purpose do you want to solve with it? do you want to have a similar windows service also for windows platform ?

If you really do not want your code to be cross platform, you can simply go with C++. If you are looking for ease of coding, again qt is a good choice.